# Is there a way to find out the syntax error?

Tags: python

I have written a code for an income tax calculator which calculates income tax of a person according to their gender. While executing, it throws in an error. I don't know why its showing an error. I am a beginner so kindly ignore if there are any silly mistakes in code

Here is an attached image for the error

[image]

```
 def incometax_calc():

    income = int(input("Enter your total annual income in lakhs: "))
    gender = str(input("Enter m if Male, f if Female: "))


    if gender == m:
        if 1<(income)<(2.5):
            tax = 0
            tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
            final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
            print("Your annual income: ",income)
            print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
            print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
            print("Final amount: ",final_amt)

    if 2.5<=(income)<5:
        tax = 10
        tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
        final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
        print("Your annual income: ",income)
        print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
        print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
        print("Final amount: ",final_amt)

    if 5<=(income)<10:
        tax = 20
        tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
        final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
        print("Your annual income: ",income)
        print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
        print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
        print("Final amount: ",final_amt)

    if (income)>10:
        tax = 30
        tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
        final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
        print("Your annual income: ",income)
        print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
        print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
        print("Final amount: ",final_amt)     

elif gender == f:
    if 1<(income)<(2.5):
        tax = 0
        tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
        final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
        print("Your annual income: ",income)
        print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
        print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
        print("Final amount: ",final_amt)

    if 2.5<=(income)<5:
        tax = 5
        tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
        final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
        print("Your annual income: ",income)
        print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
        print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
        print("Final amount: ",final_amt)

    if 5<=(income)<10:
        tax = 10
        tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
        final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
        print("Your annual income: ",income)
        print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
        print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
        print("Final amount: ",final_amt)

    if (income)>10:
        tax = 20
        tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
        final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
        print("Your annual income: ",income)
        print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
        print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
        print("Final amount: ",final_amt)
else:
    print("Wrong input!!")

print(incometax_calc())
```

Comment: You need the string `"m"`.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: a NameError is not a syntax error. Syntax errors usually occur when you are missing indentation or a parenthesis or similar. Forgetting to assign a value to a variable before using it is an entirely different category of problem.

Comment: Also, you're going to hit the `NameError: name f is not defined` soon. So better fix that too :)

Answer (score 2):

Your string comparison is wrong. It should be

```
gender == 'm'
```

Otherwise the interpreter thinks it's a variable instead of a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
if gender == m:
```

Here you are comparing to the variable called m, not the string 'm'.

To fix it make that variable into a string, like so:

```
if gender == 'm':
```

Answer (score 1):

Python thinks `m` is a variable name. Put it in quotes to compare the variable `gender` to the value `'m'`.

```
if gender == 'm':
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is here:

```
if gender == m:
```

If you write this way he looks if `m` is a variable, but you want `"m"` as a string.

Answer (score 1):

From your stack trace:

> line 8: name ‘m’ is not defined

The statement `if gender == m` throws an error because the program is looking for a variable `m`, which is not defined. If you meant to compare the variable gender to the string value `m`, then you should enclose it within double or single quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple definition error.

```
if gender == m:
```

The variable `m` has not been defined in your code before you use it.

Try something like:

```
m = "m"
if gender == m
```

OR

```
if gender == 'm'
```

if m is a [global](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/) variable that you are referencing in this method, specify

```
global m
```

before `m`'s first use.

Answer (score 0):

`m` is not defined. 
Here you are invoking m as a python object.
What you are looking for is `"m"`

Your code will look like this.

```
 def incometax_calc():

    income = int(input("Enter your total annual income in lakhs: "))
    gender = str(input("Enter m if Male, f if Female: "))


    if gender == "m":
        if 1<(income)<(2.5):
            tax = 0
            tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
            final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
            print("Your annual income: ",income)
            print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
            print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
            print("Final amount: ",final_amt)

        if 2.5<=(income)<5:
            tax = 10
            tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
            final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
            print("Your annual income: ",income)
            print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
            print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
            print("Final amount: ",final_amt)

        if 5<=(income)<10:
            tax = 20
            tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
            final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
            print("Your annual income: ",income)
            print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
            print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
            print("Final amount: ",final_amt)

        if (income)>10:
            tax = 30
            tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
            final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
            print("Your annual income: ",income)
            print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
            print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
            print("Final amount: ",final_amt)     

    elif gender == "f":
        if 1<(income)<(2.5):
            tax = 0
            tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
            final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
            print("Your annual income: ",income)
            print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
            print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
            print("Final amount: ",final_amt)

        if 2.5<=(income)<5:
            tax = 5
            tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
            final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
            print("Your annual income: ",income)
            print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
            print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
            print("Final amount: ",final_amt)

        if 5<=(income)<10:
            tax = 10
            tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
            final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
            print("Your annual income: ",income)
            print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
            print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
            print("Final amount: ",final_amt)

        if (income)>10:
            tax = 20
            tax_ded = ((tax/100)*income)
            final_amt = (income)-(tax_ded)
            print("Your annual income: ",income)
            print("Tax percentage applied: ",tax)
            print("Tax deducted: ",tax_ded)
            print("Final amount: ",final_amt)
    else:
        print("Wrong input!!")

    print(incometax_calc())
```